# How to deal with Could not cast Appdelegate to FIRMessagingDelegate

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

```
if #available(iOS 10.0, *) 
{
  // For iOS 10 display notification (sent via APNS)
  UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self as? UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate

let authOptions: UNAuthorizationOptions = [.alert, .badge, .sound]

 UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(

options: authOptions,
                completionHandler: {_, _ in })
            // For iOS 10 data message (sent via FCM

Messaging.messaging().delegate = (self as! MessagingDelegate)
```

> Couldn't cast value from Appdelegate to FIRMessagingDelegate

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need conform to the protocol in class line

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate,FIRMessagingDelegate {
```

as this cast `(self as! MessagingDelegate)` will crash , then replace it with

```
Messaging.messaging().delegate = self
```